# Matplotlib,how to represent array as image?

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib

This is what I have tried so far

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with open('base.txt','r') as f:
    vst = map(int, itertools.imap(float, f))

v1=vst[::3]
print type(v1)

a=np.asarray(v1)
print len(a)
a11=a.reshape(50,100)

plt.imshow(a11, cmap='hot')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

I have (50,100) array and each element has numerical value(range 1200-5400).I would like to have image that would represent array.But I got this
[image]

What should I change to get proper image?

Comment: How does this differ from the output you desire?

Comment: This looks like a valid heatmap...are you sure that the elements of the array should give you a different image?  It looks like after the 2nd or 3rd row, the values of the array are strictly over 5000.  Is that not the case?

Comment: @gariepy Yes,they are.Then it means I should change a heatmap?

Comment: Well, like @Reti43 said, what do you want to see?  I think the plot command you issued is working correctly.

Comment: @Reti43 I would like to see something analog to MATLAB COLORBAR,with good differentiation between the values.

Comment: Could you please plot the histogram of your data? We don't know what the image should look like. Also, try plt.imshow(a11, cmap='hot', interpolation='nearest') to avoid interpolation and see the actual value of each pixel.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't have data from `base.txt`.
However, in order to simulate your problem, I created random numbers between `1500 to 5500` and created a `50 x 100 numpy array` , which I believe is close to your data and requirement.

Then I simply plotted the data as per your plot code.
I am getting true representation of the array.
See if this helps.

**Demo Code**

```
#import itertools
import numpy as np
from numpy import array
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random


#Generate a list of 5000 int between 1200,5500
M = 5000
myList = [random.randrange(1200,5500)  for i in xrange(0,M)]

#Convert to 50 x 100 list
n = 50
newList = [myList[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(myList), n)]

#Convert to 50 x 100 numpy array
nArray = array(newList)
print nArray

a11=nArray.reshape(50,100)
plt.imshow(a11, cmap='hot')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

**Plot**
[image]